# Is it possible to integrate sage in kile?

Tags: compiling, kile, sagetex

I'm using `sagetex` to output the result of computations directly on LaTeX. I'm using Kile as my editor. The usual procedure for compilation is:

1. compile LaTeX on Kile.
2. goto terminal and load the Sage script on Sage
3. compile LaTeX again.

I was wondering if it is possible to make a build tool for Kile that does, for example:

1. `pdflatex filename.tex`
2. `sage filename.sagetex.sage`
3. `pdflatex filename.tex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create or modify build tools, go to Settings --> Configure Kile, and select Tools --> Build in the left panel. You have to create two new tools, one for just running `sage filename.sage`, one for the sequence of tools.

#### Tool for running `sage`

1. Click the *New* button below the list of existing tools, call the new tool for example *Sage*.
2. Click *Next* and then *Finish*, you don't have to specify the class.
3. In the *General* tab for the new tool, type `sage` as the command, and `'%S.sage'` as an option. `%S` is, as I understand it, a placeholder for the filename without extension. (I just looked at how other tools, e.g. MakeIndex, is set up.)

In the *Advanced*  tab you can fill in source and target extension, but I do not know if this is necessary to include. If it is, I guess the source extension is `sage` and the target `sout`. (According to http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/sagetex.html)

#### Tool for the sequence

1. Create a new tool with a reasonable name, but this time select **Quick build** as the class.
2. In the *General*  tab, you can choose from existing tools, and combine these in a sequence. Select tool you want from the drop-down menu and click *Add* to add it to the sequence. Add the *PDFLaTeX* tool twice, and the *Sage*  tool you just created in between.

The new tool is found under Build --> Other. You can add a keyboard shortcut if you like, by going to Settings --> Configure Shortcuts.

Comment: I have Sage installed and went through the instructions but it didn't work. In "Tool for running sage", I change '%S.sagetex.tex' to '%S.sage' and then it worked but for some strange reason clicking on the ViewPDF button key now gives an error ("ViewPDF failed to start"). If I double-click on the PDF it opens and I can see the changes. With the PDF open compiling using the sequence works perfectly. PS: I didn't fill in source and target. +1!

Comment: @DJP Thanks for testing. First of all, I see that I made a silly mistake, according to the question it should be `filename.sagetex.sage`, not `filename.sagetex.tex`. Second, reading on sagemath.org, I see that `sagetex` produces a file called `filename.sage`, not `filename.sagetex.sage`, so the OP apparently made a mistake. I'll fix it immediately. No idea why the ViewPDF failed though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the instructions. For some reason, in my case, the sage script has extension `.sagetex.sage`. Just as a personal preference, on the tool for sequence under the tab Menu, I selected Add to Build menu: Compile. That way I have easy access along with the other tools for compilation

Comment: @Barefeg: Adding a button to do a 1 touch compile (as opposed to the keyboard shortcut) is a useful touch. Thanks. I will have to start using Kile more.