# Strange result when trying to use sagetex

Tags: sagetex

As a result of another question I'm trying to use Sagetex. I performed the install as directed, and even got the compile to succeed, insofar as there are no fatal errors, but it appears that sagetex isn't actually parsing anything in sage like it should.

```
\begin{sagesilent}
var("x") #test
Integer(randint(1,4))
a = Integer(randint(2,7))*x+Integer(randint(2,7))
b = Integer(randint(2,7))*x+Integer(randint(2,7))
\end{sagesilent}

This is a test
$(\sage{a})(\sage{b}) = \sage{expand(a*b)}$
```

Compiles into

```
This is a test
(??)(??)=??
```

So it seems like the variable x, and the "a" and "b" are not actually staying defined (or maybe not being defined in the first place).

In contrast, the exact same code in sagecloud defines 2 binomials perfectly fine, then expands them like it should.

The only error I get from latex is "LaTeX Warning: Reference `@sageinline0' on page 1 undefined on input line 120." about 3 times.

For what it's worth I'm using Texmaker as my editor.

Comment: I've not used sagetex, but this sounds like the kind of error you see when you need to compile multiple times to get references right. Have you tried that?

Comment: It does look exactly like that type of error, which is why I tried that first... sadly with no luck.

Comment: Compilation is 3 step steps. First run LaTeX on your file. In addition to creating the log file you also end up with a .sage file. You've got to compile that file with Sage . Then the third step is to run LaTeX on the LaTeX file. That slow process can be sped up in some IDE's; for example with Kile, discussed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96409/is-it-possible-to-integrate-sage-in-kile/96539#96539). The easiest way is to use Sagemath Cloud and one click of Sage does everything. If you've done 3 step process try [this](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/sagetex.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying I have to hit compile on the Latex side. Then load up the sage file and hit compile on that. Then reload the doc in my latex editor and compile again?

Comment: Yes. But you aren't compiling the .sage file with LaTeX, you compile with Sage. Processing with Sage performs the calculations. Running LaTeX the final time works the calculations in. Slow, unless you've configured an IDE to chain the commands together so one click does the work. See the link to the Kile question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have an IDE programmed to compile the document with 1 click, it's a 3 step process:
Step 1: Process your file with LaTeX. This produces a .sage file
[image]
Step 2: Compile the .sage file using Sage. That means getting the terminal open for Sage. Make sure you've changed to that directory (cd). Type load("MyFile.sagetex.sage") and press return. This performs the calculations and creates more files (eg .sout)
[image]
Step 3: process the .tex file with LaTeX

If you've done this and things still aren't working, it could be that Sage and LaTeX aren't talking to each other. See [this page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/sagetex.html) for more information.

Comment: This was exactly it, thanks!
Do you happen to know why I get the missing latexmk.sty file error when I try to use latexmk? Google doesn't seem to have anything about the sty file, and it doesn't appear to be in the package download.

Comment: I don't know much about latexmk.sty but I did a little searching and found [this](https://bitbucket.org/ddrake/sagetex/wiki/UsingSageTeX).

Comment: I spent several hours trying to get it to work with Texmaker, and still haven't figured out how to integrate latexmk to get it to auto compile correctly. I really like Texmaker's interface and editing options, but at this point I may move to sagemath cloud since I can't seem to figure out how to get Texmaker to work.

Comment: This [link](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/10109/sagetex-integration-with-texmaker/) confirms that the link I gave above works with TeXmaker. If you're unable to get it to work, you should try posting for a clarification on AskSagemath.

Comment: I was able to get sagetex running in TexMaker. Were you successful?

Comment: @Jason I was able to get sagetex running in Texmaker. Were you successful?

Comment: I was not, I have them linked together, but I can't hit the compile button once and have everything working... I assume it has to do with latexmk configuration. I found the latexmkrc file in the asymptote folder which is what (I think) I'm suppose to add those lines of code to, but no dice. Is there something I need to change in TexMaker other than switching to the compile with latexmk + pdf option?

Comment: @Jason Key step was to configure one of the commands (eg metapost) to activate Sage. Then defined Quickbuild to run pdflatex, Sage, pdflatex, and pdfViewer. I don't know basics of latexmk. See if you can run as I did. If you can't post a question and I'll walk through what I did with screenshots.

Comment: Yea, I'll be honest, I have absolutely no idea how to make the custom command to run Sage... any help would be appreciated.
Also, thanks a ton for the help in general, it's really appreciated.

Comment: @Jason Please post the question and I will explain. I confirmed it works with latexmk, too.

Comment: I'm not sure how to configure one of the commands to activate sage. I know how to configure Quickbuild to do a custom set (or, I can for normal options, I won't know if it works for the custom commands until I try).
I tried with the latexmk and it just seems to do nothing at all, so I assume something's not configured right, but since I don't get any error (other than the one saying sage isn't compiled yet) I haven't been able to narrow down what the actual issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25133/discussion-between-djp-and-jason).