# Is there a math package with a set of macros that would help manipulate terms in long expressions?

Tags: math-mode, macros

This semester I've been typesetting my math homeworks in Latex, and these often involve long expressions with many fractions and brackets. I'd love to be able to use macros to perform operations like expanding brackets, collecting like terms, factorizing polynomials, etc. Things like:

```
(a + b)( c + d) = ac + ab + bc + bd
a/b = c/d --> ad = bc 
(a + b + c)^2 = ...
```

It would be even better if there are macros that combine operations like these to execute more complicated tasks like rewriting an equation in terms of one of the variables.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It will be better if you show us your compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that you have tried so far. Also, you should add the math formulas as an image instead of some lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sagetex` package gives you access to a computer algebra system, called SAGE, which can help. SAGE documentation for Symbolic equations is [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/relation.html) and documentation for the package is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). Here is a sample of how you can combine SAGE with LaTeX through `sagetex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
a,b,c,d = var("a,b,c,d")
eqn = a/b==c/d
\end{sagesilent}
Given variables $a, b, c$, and $d$; then:\\
$(a+b)(c+d)=\sage{expand((a+b)*(c+d))}$ and \\
$(a+b+c)^2=\sage{expand((a+b+c)^2)}$. \\
Moreover, $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ implies $\sage{(b*d)*eqn}$
\begin{sagesilent}
y=var("y")
f = x^2 + y^2 == 1
solutions = f.solve(x)
\end{sagesilent}

If you have the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ then solving for $x$ gives
$\sage{f.solve(x)[0]}$ and $\sage{f.solve(x)[1]}$ 
\end{document}
```

SAGE recognizes x as a default variable, everything else should be declared using var(). Set up the calculations in SAGE through `sagesilent` and access the results using \sage{}. SAGE is not part of the LaTeX distribution so it should be installed on your computer or accessed through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. The result of the code being compiled is shown below:
[image]

It's easy to make a mistake typesetting math as you did in the first equation. SAGE helps eliminate mistakes.

Comment: +1 I didn't know either `sagetex` or `SAGE`, it's excellent, a thousand thanks!

Comment: I just installed `SAGE` on my windows 10 with MikTeX and there are question marks (??) instead of results, do you know why?

Comment: Most likely this is because you are assuming that you can just LaTeX your document and be done. That won't work because SAGE needs to run. The documentation explains it's a 3 step process. My answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/strange-result-when-trying-to-use-sagetex/251466#251466) might help. If that doesn't work then it's probably a communication problem between TeX and SAGE which is addressed [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html?highlight=latex%20sage).