# Exercises with solutions math's sheet : packages or template advice needed

Tags: exercises, teaching

I would like to create a exercises&solutions math's sheet for my students.

I would love to be able to insert each exercise and solution in one section like :

```
\begin{exercise)
  $(2x-3)^2-(3x+2)^2=$
\end{exercise)
\begin{solution)
  $-(x+5)(5x-1)$
\end{solution)
```

and to be able to have that kind of rendering when compiling :

[image]

I looked at some packages [here](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise) but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

Do you have some advices for me ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but isn't that just rendering inputted math, with two sections? Possibly making one section float to the left.

Comment: You should consider using the `sagetex` package as it can do the algebra problems. This makes it less likely that there is a mistake in your answer key. See, for example, the selected answer to the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460400/is-there-a-math-package-with-a-set-of-macros-that-would-help-manipulate-terms-in/460401#460401).

Answer (score 4):

This is doable (with not quite the required syntax, but…) with not *too* much effort with `xsim`.

The main idea is:

- create templates for the desired layout
- use the same environment body both for exercises *and* solutions using the parameter `solution` as option to the exercise environment (instead of setting this manually as option to each exercise it could also be built in into the template in order to set it automatically)
- create a shortcut for `\IfInsideSolutionTF` to still be able to use different content in exercises and solutions
- setup `xsim` to use the new templates

Please ask if something in the code is unclear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{tasks}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
  \noindent\sffamily
  \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{\hspace{3em}{\small#1}}\par
  \normalfont
}{}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{flushright}{%
  \begin{flushright}
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \textsf{Solutions:}\par\normalfont
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{flushright}%
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/template = custom ,
  solution/template = flushright
}

\renewcommand*\theexercise{\thesection-\arabic{exercise}}

\newcommand\QA[2]{\IfInsideSolutionTF{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{exercise}{30}

\begin{exercise}[ID=one,solution,subtitle=Factorize as much as possible the following expressions.]
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \QA{$(2x-3)^2 - (3x-2)^2 =$}{$-(x+5)(5x-1)$}
    \task \QA{$(x^2-25) - 2(5-x)(x+6) =$}{$(x+5)(3x-17)$}
    \task \QA{$2x(x+2) + (x+1)^2 + 2 =$}{$3(x+1)^2$}
  \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}
\printsolution{exercise}{one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh ! @cgnieder : I'm amazed ! I'm far away to know as much as you on Latex... Thx you so much for the time you took to code this answer.