# How to use sagetex?

Tags: sagetex

I am trying to use sagetex. Now in the console in sage it is written:"Sage processing complete. Run LaTeX on Beiapiel5.tex again." But when I compile the latex code again nothing happens. Now I have taken the example at the Sagemath site. I have pasted the code into Texmaker  called the file st_example.tex. After running it in sage I have got the files,  st_example.sagetex.sout,st_example.sagetex.scmd,sage-plots-for-st_example.tex,st_example.sagetex.sage.py.

Comment: You never said you used LaTeX before Sage. To use `sagetex` you need LaTeX code such as the example at the [Sagemath site](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html); call it MyFile.tex. First, you run LaTeX on that, to create a `.sage` file. Second, you process that using Sage, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/strange-result-when-trying-to-use-sagetex). Finally, run LaTeX on that to create MyFile.pdf which will be in the same directory. If you have no pdf file, there should be an error message in MyFile.log. What does it say?

Comment: Be sure your tex system knows the location of the current version of `sagetex.sty`. That style file is included within the Sage distribution or may be downloaded from CTAN.

Comment: You give no information whatsoever as to your platform or configuration. Please do!

Comment: If you are using MacTeX, then things are easy: after you have made tex aware of the location of `sagetex.sty`, then either: (1) copy the file `sage.engine` from `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Sage` to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`, edit it so that the version of Sage referenced is your actual version, put `% !TEX TS-program = sage` at the top of your file, and Typeset using the sage engine;  or else copy `platexmkrc` from `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Sage` into the same folder as your source `.tex` file, put `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk`, and Typeset using the pdflatexmk engine.

Comment: Now that you have run latex on the `.tex` file and run Sage on the `.sage` file, run latex on the `.tex` file again. It will take the files you mentioned to construct the final document. If you ran latex with a `pdflatex` command, you should have a `MyFile.pdf` at the end. If you ran latex with a `latex` command, you should have a `MyFile.dvi` file at the end. If you have neither, open `MyFile.log` and read the error message. What does it say?

Comment: I have got  both  st_example.dvi and st_example.pdf but there are still the question marks

Comment: the log file says :Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)

Comment: That's not the error message. It should be near the bottom, before the final stats are shown. Someone is having essentially the same problem on AskSagemath. See the post [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/51945/problems-with-sagetex/) along with the answer and comments.