# Texmaker configuration and SageTex

Tags: texmaker, sagetex

I recently installed `SageMath` on my linux and tried `SageTex` on `Texmaker` as follows:

run `pdflatex` on Texmaker, run `load("example.sagetex.sage")` from the `build folder` with Sage,
and run `pdflatex` on Texmaker again.

The only catch is that I have to move the `sage-plot-for-example.tex` folder *(generated plot figures by Sage)* in the same `directory/folder` of the `example.tex` file. Otherwise, error occurs.

This would not be needed if the option for `use a build subdirectory for output files` is not checked in the Texmaker configuration. But I like the subdirectory as I feel the files are more neatly arranged. For similar problems with `Bib(la)tex` and `Makeindex`, this can be resolved by replacing the directory options `bibtex %.aux` with `bibtex build\%.aux` and `makeindex %.idx` with `makeindex build\%.idx` in the Texmaker configuration under 'Commands'.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure this in texmaker?

Any help or suggestion? Thanks!

**Edits** `Sagetex` works just fine with `use a build subdirectory for output files` option if the `sage codes` have nothing to do with figures.

Comment: @AndreC, Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Did you try the usual instructions instead of using `load()` ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, **sage**: `sage example.sagetex.sage`     returns the error ---                                               
  File "<ipython-input-1-555918340150>", line 1
    sage example.sagetex.sage
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.                                     So, I had to use the one mentioned here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/strange-result-when-trying-to-use-sagetex instead.

Comment: Could you please post the first few lines of `example.sagetex.sage` - and the full error message, if possible?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, these are the first few lines ... `## -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
## This file (example.sagetex.sage) was *autogenerated* from example.tex with sagetex.sty version 2019/11/14 v3.4.
import sagetex
_st_ = sagetex.SageTeXProcessor('example', version='2019/11/14 v3.4', version_check=True)
try: 
 _st_.current_tex_line = 35
 _st_.inline(0, latex(2+2))
except:
 _st_.goboom(35)`

Comment: and the **error** -- `sage: sage example.sagetex.sage                                                 
  File "<ipython-input-1-555918340150>", line 1
    sage example.sagetex.sage
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: what Sage version are you using?

Comment: 9.0 has a very old version of Sagetex, that is, its Python part might not match Sagetex 3.4 that you are using.

Comment: You probably have incompatible TeX and Python parts of sagtex - only one of them is v3.4, as printed in your error message. Where/how have you got the TeX part?

(I don't know anything about texmaker, sorry - feel free to tell the details)

Comment: I installed texlive (various versions and not texlive 2020). Do you think an installation of the latest texlive will solve it?

Comment: I gather installing texlive might not install the Python part of sagetx correctly

Comment: do you think miktex would work better with it?

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with texlive/miktex, per se. SageTeX has TeX style files and Python files, they must play together to work right. 

By the way, is your Sage Python 2 or Python 3? (cf. the 2nd line of the Sage banner)

Comment: 3.8.2, to be precise.

Comment: well, we're officially supporting only Python 3.7 in Sage, not 3.8... Is this provided by a Linux distro, such as arch?

Comment: yes, linux mint 20.

Comment: what you see if you start sage, and then  do

```
sage: import sagetex
sage: sagetex.pyversion
```

Comment: sorry, `sage:` is the prompt. The text to type is `import sagetex` <enter>
`sagetex.pyversion` <enter>

Comment: `'2019/11/14 v3.4'`

Comment: OK, so Python files of   sagetex are  up to date. How about TeX? In the directory where you run latex on `example.tex`, could you run `grep "Package: sagetex" example.log` and post the output (this should tell the TeX files version)

Comment: the latter should be run at the shell prompt. By the way, the same applies to your attempt to run `sage` on `example.sagetex.sage`. The shell command to run is `sage example.sagetex.sage`.

(Trying this at `sage:` ptompt will produce the error you showed above - apologies for mis-reading - I was a.f.k. then)

Comment: shell, a.k.a. bash, a.k.a. terminal, a.k.a. `shell prompt`, a.k.a. `bash prompt`

Comment: $ `grep "Package: sagetex" example.log` returns `Package: sagetex 2019/11/14 v3.4 embedding Sage into LaTeX documents`

Comment: A view of the first few lines of `example.log` is as follows:     `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.17)  21 JUL 2020 23:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**example.tex
(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>`

Comment: do you get correct results if you use shell prompt to run  `sage example.sagetex.sage`

Comment: yes, I got it now. previously, i used to run `sage example.sagetex.sage` on sage, which was the reason for the problem, perhaps on `sage` it should be `example.sagetex.sage`. @DimaPasechnik Thanks! But I am still stuck with having to move the sage output folder (for sage generated figures) in the same directory with my `example.tex` file.

Comment: do you have this problem if you do everything at the shell prompt?

Comment: no problem with that. like i mentioned in the post, `use a build subdirectory for output files` in texmaker option keeps the output files neat which i liked. without this option, everything works just fine. my problem is `texmaker` specific but thanks to you, some of my auxiliary problems have been resolved @DimaPasechnik. **Ps** I am new to `linux` as well as `sagemath`