# Integrating SageTex and Kile/TexStudio in Linux

Tags: latexmk, kile, sagetex

I had followed the instructions given in the answer to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96409/is-it-possible-to-integrate-sage-in-kile), but it seems that sage never gets launched once pdf is created in that integration. I am attaching screenshot of log and messages which popped up.

[image]

Due to my desperation, I tried using Latexmk to do this job. After learning what is .latexmkrc/LatexMk file (hopefully), I tried to build one as as described [here](https://github.com/sagemath/sagetex/wiki), although very naively. I just copied and pasted the code given in a fresh text and placed it in *$HOME/.latexmkrc*.

I ran the command **latexmk myfile.tex** and it gave me only PDF again, without running sage. I am sorry but I am unable to find a way to copy/paste huge amount of data my terminal spouted out. I will wait for you to tell me what specifically to post out of it.

Interesting point: Just once and no more, when using latexmk myfie.tex, terminal recongzied the RC file in home directory and said there are errors in it.

**I just want a way to click a button and compile my documents, doesn't matter which way. I beg you people to lend me a hand. Will be very grateful.**

---

I am on Linux Mint 18.1, currently a noob. 
Using TeX for quite some time now, thanks to TeX community. Will try my best to follow your instructions.

Comment: There are instructions for integrating Kile with sagetex [here](http://www.highschoolmathandchess.com/pythonsage/integrating-sagetex-and-kile/) using lots of pictures. I tried them with my computer (Linux Mint 18.1). The interface with Kile looks different now (post was written in 2013) but I got it to work in less than 10 minutes of tinkering.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. I tried this already. I tried again, for the heck of it.  After choosing type as "Run Sequence of Tools", If I choose the class "compile", [as this link suggests] I get nothing at all. However, if I choose the "sequence" class I get what is in the image. Any suggestion?

Comment: Problem is in SAGE. I tried to run it separately and it shows the same error as above - failed to start **[SAGE] failed to start**

Comment: The error in your picture about Sage failed to start indicates, I think, that Sage never ran. Some possible things to check: 1.  ' marks as in : '%S.sage' 2. Two tools under build--I called one Sage which is Type  Run outside of Kile and Class Compile. The second tool I called SagePDF which is Type Run Sequence of Tools and Class Sequence. Under the General tab it is tool Archive, Current Default tar +gzip. 3. the box next to the Add/Remove/Up/Down buttons it says PDFLaTeX above Sage above PDFLaTeX above ViewPDF. Mine says Sage rather than the SAGE (as in link) because that's my Tool.

Comment: Try opening a terminal and typing: sage to see if sage starts, too. Sage is not part of LaTeX distribution, so it needs to be installed on your machine and this [link](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html) talks about making sure Sage and LaTeX are talking to one another.

Comment: Yes, I can run sage that way. I ensured that I can do that. My settings are just like yours, apart from the names. I am not too sure, but it seems to me (from picture) that sage is trying to run a .tex file.. is that so?

Comment: No. First pass of LaTeX should create a .sage file Second pass sage processes file and creates .sout file. third pass puts the Sage calculations into the document.

Comment: Mine gives similar message, though.

Comment: So, there's not much progress. Well, ok, I will wait