# SageTex on PC MikTeX issue

Tags: sagetex

I am trying to run the LaTeX/SageTeX code presented in [John Palmieri](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20404/how-to-create-a-random-math-problem-in-latex) answer. The file compiles, but the output PDF is missing all mathematical Sage answers and yet there are no error messages (e.g, no complaint that sagetex.sty or anything else not found).

I am running MiKTeX on a PC and have installed sagetex package. I am wondering what steps I have missed. Do I need additional steps informing MiKTeX of where my Sage is?

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, then Sage, then LaTeX again?

Comment: No I just ran LaTeX, under impression that the process is automated.

Comment: You can find a little more explanation of the process in the answers to [How to use sagetex package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502866/how-to-use-sagetex-package/503204#503204) and as well as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251459/strange-result-when-trying-to-use-sagetex/251466#251466)

Comment: Also compiling the latex code on sage/cocalc automatically handles all sage/latex issues.